# System.Action<T> as EventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, action, event-handling, func

What speaks against using the delegates `System.Action` or `System.Func` as EventDelegates instead of the classic `EventHandler` pattern. Will I therefore run into problems?

```
private bool disposed;

public event Action<IUnitOfWork, IContext> Disposing;

public void Dispose()
{
    if (this.disposed)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (null != this.Disposing)
    {
        this.Disposing(this, this.AttachedContext);
    }

    this.disposed = true;
}
```

Usage:

```
unitOfWorkInstance.Disposing += (u, c) => c.Rollback(u); // in my opinion more readable than
unitOfWorkInstance.Disposing += (sender, args) => args.AttachedContext.Rollback(sender as IUnitOfWork);
```

Comment: Dispose method [...] should be callable multiple times without throwing an exception. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint. In this case I replace the exception with a simple return.

Comment: While this is creative (+1), I don't see what problem it is solving. For one, isn't the definition of `disposingInternal` still going to be a delegate... You (purposely?) left it out of the code snippet so perhaps you're going to surprise me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the code you've given there isn't thread-safe - someone could unsubscribe from the eventhandler after your nullity test and before your call `this.Disposing`.

But in general, it should work just fine. The downside is that by not following the `EventHandler` convention, you're slightly more limited in terms of what can subscribe.

For example, suppose you have a very general event handler method:

```
public void LogEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Event raised");
}
```

You can use this to subscribe to *any* event following the normal convention - but not with 
your event.

This is a pretty minor downside though. I guess a potentially bigger one is that it may confuse other developers who are *expecting* to see a conventional event signature.

EDIT: I've just remembered that some other libraries may expect the conventional event signature - Reactive Extensions does, for example. IIRC, it's not impossible to subscribe to other events, just a bit harder.

Comment: Agreeing with what you said, "This is a pretty minor downside though" - Depending on how much control they have, they could adapt it with a lambda: `unitOfWork.Disposing += (uow, context) => LogEvent(uow, new EventArgs());`.

Comment: FWIW: I religiously avoid the `object sender, EventArgs e` usually. That said, I tend to avoid using Event delegates unless I really require multicast semantics. I see what the flexibility of the 'standard signature' is, but 90% of the time that is an academic benefit that costs code readability. In framework design, I'd vouch _for_ standard Event signatures, nonetheless

Comment: +1 for mentioning reactive extensions :D

Answer (score 2):

From a "does-the-code-work" perspective, I would say it is perfectly OK to use these delegate types for events.

The problem with doing this, is that you are not following the common pattern for events, where the delegate is `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`, and TEventArgs is a custom type that contains the parameters for the event. The benefits of following this pattern include:

- Code readability
- Not having to change event subscribers if you need to add a parameter to the events (because you will just add it to your custom event arguments class).

Answer (score 1):

**In general:**

There is no problem with using `Action` as your event handler.  It is supported by the language, so use it :)

The only case I can think of is code that tries to find your events via reflections.  But if that code couldn't handle any delegate as an event type, I'd say their code was buggy, not yours.

**Your specific example:**

The problem with the pattern you are using is that you shouldn't really be using the object while in the `Dispose` method.  It could be safe sometimes, but would be easy to get wrong.

For example, if the `Dispose` method disposed resources before raising the event, then the object would be in an unusable state.

This could be hard (without comments and strong code reviews) for a maintenance programmer to get right when editing your `Dispose` method.

Comment: the only public members of my this UnitOfWork implementation are: `Commit()/Rollback()/Dispose() and Disposing`. The Disposing event will only inform other objects (Transation/DataContext). In my class i haven't any ressource management.

Comment: @ben: Exception safety is another example of a high priority concern in this scenario.  Adding events to `Dispose` methods will make it that much harder to ensure exception safety (including double-throws).  Unless you have a really good reason to justify the added complexity, I think you might be shooting yourself in the foot.  But my advice is free to take or leave as you wish :)

Comment: @Ben dotnet: And the maintenance programmer point implies we're talking also about how this code will look years from now, on future versions, not just what your current implementation contains.  (and in my experience, 2 months from now when you haven't looked at the code in a while, and have to come back to fix a bug)